# How to set grid-template

Tags: css

My CSS is shown below. What I want is the header shall be fixed at top of the page and having width equal to the width of container irrespective to the changing width of browser. However, I always get the width of header expands over the width of container. Please instruct me how to fix it.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 170px 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="cart">
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: What is the grid host, `.container` or `header`?

Comment: That's because by setting it to position: fixed, you pull the header out of the document flow. It's like it isn't inside container anymore. One quick fix would be to set the width to 80% (the same as container)

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I have tried. Set the width of header 80%. This time the width of header is always smaller the width of container that I expect. I need the header fixed at top of page so that below elements can be scrolled up below it.

Comment: header is child element of container.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the `header` to 80%;

Works automatically..

```css
 * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150vh;
}

header {
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="cart">
    </div>
  </header>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Jqewmy)